# Renaming a data frame using the value of a string

Tags: r, dataframe, naming

Is there a way to rename a data frame using the value of a string?

I'm trying to write a function in [R] that takes a vector of values, operates over them, and (among other things) returns a data frame to the global environment using the <<- operator. I'd like the name of this data frame to reflect the name of the vector used to create it.

Ideally the code would look something like this:

```
my.func <- function(vector.in){

# ... Operations over vector.in ... #

data.out <- data.frame(x1 = ...)
new.name <- paste("data.out", deparse(substitute(vector.in)), sep="_")

#Change the name of data.out to the value of the string new.name
changename(data.out, new.name)

#Export the newly named object to the global environment
new.name <<- new.name

# ... More operations ... #

}
```

Comment: I actually didn't think this was a perfect duplicate, although there probably is one somewhere ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
assign(newname, data.out, envir = .Global.env)
```

should do what you want (also replaces the `<<-` call) -- but there's probably a more idiomatic/R-like way to manage your objects so you don't have to do this ...